# Work Manager not working in flutter when implementing in native side

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-workmanager

-I am developing app in Flutter and I need to run some code of line in background for specific time on everyday so i implemented work manager in native and then i pass call to flutter using method channel but the Problem is WorkManager Not Working in Background Or After Terminating Application. (I am Running Application on Android-11 and Samsung Device)

here is my code..

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        NativeMethodChannel.configureChannel(flutterEngine);
        setUpWorker();
    }

    private void setUpWorker() {
        WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this);
        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicSyncDataWork =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .build();
        workManager.enqueue(
                periodicSyncDataWork //work request
        );
    }
}

public class NativeMethodChannel {
    private static MethodChannel methodChannel;

    public static void configureChannel(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        String CHANNEL_NAME = "com.example.mutual_fund/android";
        methodChannel = new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL_NAME);
    }

    public static void sendBroadcastString(String broadcastType) {
        methodChannel.invokeMethod(broadcastType, broadcastType);
    }
}

public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public NotificationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        try{
            Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    NativeMethodChannel.sendBroadcastString(Constants.internet_available_method);
                } 
            };
            mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
        }catch (Exception error){
            Log.d("Worker Error-----", error.getMessage());
        }
        return Result.success();
    }
}

class FlutterMethodChannel {
  static const channelName =
      'com.example.mutual_fund/android'; // this channel name needs to match the one in Native method channel
  late MethodChannel methodChannel;

  static FlutterMethodChannel instance = FlutterMethodChannel();

  void configureChannel() {
    methodChannel = const MethodChannel(channelName);
    methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(methodHandler);
  }


  Future<void> methodHandler(MethodCall call) async {
    switch (call.method) {
      case "internet_available_method":
        print("internet_available_method called from native android code");
        Get.put(AlertController()).sendBackgroundAlertNotifications();
        break;
      case "no_internet_connection_method":
        print("no_internet_connection_method called from native android code");
        break;
      default:
        print('no method handler for method ${call.method}');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Because when app is killed, Flutter and dart VM is killed too, the methodChannel will be null

Comment: did you find a way around it? another library or something?